# Expectation of log sum lognormal random variables

Tags: logistic, logit, lognormal-distribution

I wonder if there exists any good approximation solution to the following quantity:

Vector $X \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$, what would be the Expectation of $y=\log\left[\sum\exp\left(x_i\right)\right]$?
I know a closed form solution probably doesn't exist, but even some good bound would be of help.

This appears when I have a logistic normal probability and I'm trying to compute $E\log \frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum\exp(x_i)}$ for each i.

Comment: This is known in some fields as [conservation of lognormality](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11004-005-7306-7).

Comment: How does knowing this help you solve the problem in the last sentence?

Comment: @Glen_b Hi, the E$ log \frac{exp(x_i)}{\sum exp(x_i)}$ is simply $E(x_i)-E(log \sum (exp(x_i)))$. Since $E(x_i)$ is simply $\mu_i$, the second term is all I need